# 2 Excel button on two different datatables on the same page

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, datatables

I have a web service with 2 web methods to pull data from the SQL and display it on two Datatables on the same web page.

When I have just only one "Excel" button, then i am getting my data in excel, when the button is pressed. But if i have 2 buttons, then the first datatable button is working, but the 2nd datatable excel button is not working, and saving it as a spreadsheet. If i placed any other button, like 'pdf', 'csv',..then the 2nd button also works, saving the data accordingly to the specified format.

My 2 jQuery DataTable implementation :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'Service.asmx/LoadReport',
           method: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
         $('#datatable').dataTable({
                   data: data,
                   dom: 'Bfrtip', 
                   buttons: [
                     //    //'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                     //    'excel'
                     { extend: 'excel', text: 'Save as Excel', filename: "SubmissionStatus" }
                   ],
                   columns:  ….
         }); 
           }
       }); 
   });
```

and my second implementation :

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'Service.asmx/LoadTars',
           method: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
               $('#datatable2').dataTable({
                   data: data,
                   dom: 'Bfrtip',
                   buttons: [ 
                        'excel'
                     //    { extend: 'excel', text: 'Save as Excel'}
                   ],
                   columns: ….
               });
           }
       });
   });
```

and these are the CDNs I am referencing to:

script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Could you point out why my 2nd excel button is not saving the data to the specified format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the culprit - it's the old version of js that i was referencing for jquery [**code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js** ] was causing this issue, not to have 2 excel buttons on the same page for 2 different datatables.

> The correct JS reference [ **[here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js)** ] solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is.   I set up two tables on jsbin and it is working fine. http://jsbin.com/gabara/edit?html,js,output

Keep in mind that if you are running in serverSide mode, only what you see in the client will be exported so if you are paging back to the server, you will only get one page in Excel.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#example').DataTable({
            "data": dataStore.data1,
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
            ], dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['excelHtml5']
        });


        $('#example2').DataTable({
            "data": dataStore.data2,
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
            ], dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [

            'excelHtml5'
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response - i found out the culprit - it's the old version of js that i was referencing for jquery [http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js ] was causing this issue, not to have 2 excel buttons on the same page for 2 different datatables.

Comment: The correct JS reference [ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js ] solved this issue.